# Passing value into editorfor when click on a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a page contains the following links with the value in behind.

for example:

Example link: [654465465](http://www.example.com/)!

When user click on a link the url will be fetch to  http://www.example.com/654465465

at this point.

how do I allow a value 654465465 remain inside @html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)

this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult index()
    {
        var model = new myModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying, the routing in your url will have a value in it, and you want that value passed into the EditorFor?

Depending on your routing, you can specify values to obtain from the url, for example the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Specifies an id at the end. So for example if you have a url like "/myController/myAction/654465465" then 654465465 is the id in this example.

Then you'd pass it into your model like

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{ 
    var model = new myModel();
    model.Value = id;
    return View(model); 
}
```

Then when you call

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)
```

it will contain 654465465 in your input created by editorfor.